# Why is there different MSE for cross-validation data in h2o package

Tags: r, h2o

In the summary output the MSE for cross-validation data is 0.1641124, however, it is 0.14977892 in the  detailed Cross-Validation Metrics Summary. Are they not the same metrics?

```
library(h2o)

h <- h2o.init()
data <- as.h2o(iris)
part <- h2o.splitFrame(data, 0.7, seed = 123)
train <- part[[1]]
test <- part[[2]]

m <- h2o.glm(x=2:5,y=1,train, nfolds = 10, seed = 123)
summary(m)


#...
#H2ORegressionMetrics: glm

#** Reported on cross-validation data. **
#** 10-fold cross-validation on training data (Metrics computed for combined 
#holdout predictions) **

#MSE:  ***0.1641124***
#RMSE:  0.4051079
#... 

#Cross-Validation Metrics Summary: 
#  mean  sd  cv_1_valid cv_2_valid cv_3_valid  cv_4_valid  cv_5_valid cv_6_valid  cv_7_valid cv_8_valid cv_9_valid


#...

#  mse  ***0.14977892*** 0.053578787  0.14102486 0.14244498 0.05266633  0.19028585 0.043878503 0.12635022  0.13820939 0.15831167 0.33359975
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two MSE values are calculated differently.

The first one (0.1641124) is calculated using all the predictions on the hold out sets during cross validation:

create model:

```
m <- h2o.glm(x = 2:5,
             y = 1,
             train,
             nfolds = 10,
             seed = 123,
             keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
             keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment = TRUE)
```

extract hold out predictions

```
preds <- as.data.frame(h2o.cross_validation_holdout_predictions(m))
```

calculate MSE:

```
mean((preds$predict - as.data.frame(train)$Sepal.Length)^2)
#output
0.1641125
```

wheres the lower MSE (0.14977892) represents the average of MSE for each hold out set:

```
folds <- as.data.frame(h2o.cross_validation_fold_assignment(m))

library(tidyverse)
data.frame(preds = preds$predict,  #create a data frame with hold out predictions
           folds = folds$fold_assignment,  #folds assignement
           true = as.data.frame(train)$Sepal.Length) %>% #true values
  group_by(folds) %>% #group by folds 
  summarise(mse = mean((preds - true)^2)) %>% # calculate mse for each fold
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(mse = mean(mse)) %>% #average them
  as.numeric
#output
0.1497789
```

to reproduce first run:

```
library(h2o)

h <- h2o.init()
data <- as.h2o(iris)
part <- h2o.splitFrame(data, 0.7, seed = 123)
train <- part[[1]]
test <- part[[2]]
```

Comment: Thanks, which one should be used as the representative of the CV?

Comment: This is totally up to you, just be careful when you compare the models to always use the same one. I usually tend to use the mean of the hold out predictions (in this case the second one) since like this I also get some sense of variance in the performance. Then again I also tend to do repeated CV for most scenarios, in which case one can use a metric calculated on combined hold out predictions for each repeat and still get a sense of model performance variance in CV repetitions. There are no hard rules here.

Comment: When I have a two class problem and want to plot the ROC curve I need to use the combined hold out predictions or I would end up with 10 ROC curves (for 10-fold CV) in that case I report/compare the AUC on the combined predictions.

Comment: @Minyi Han Glad to help. If the answer was helpful and resolved your question, kindly accept it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).